# Drupal block visibility on views pages

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

I currently have the following PHP code to control the visibility of a block:

```
<?php
if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1)) && (arg(2) == NULL)) {
return TRUE;
}
else {
return FALSE;
}
?>
```

This works a treat in displaying the block on all view node pages, whilst hiding the view when editing or adding a node.

The problem I'm having is that a number of my Drupal pages are generated from Views. I need this block to appear on these Views generated pages as well as the pages created directly through the CMS.

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: When you create a view, you set up the path, right? If you have a common structure to all your views paths, then you can easily add that to your `if` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for poiting me in the right direction, found the answer I needed from this comment: http://drupal.org/node/134425#comment-834545